# Hue unable to access Solr Collections in CDH

Tags: hadoop, solr, cloudera, hue

I am using CDH 4 and setup Hue and Solr. I have also created collection in Solr which can be accessed from Solr UI. But I am unable to see this collection in Hue.

When I checked Hue log, I saw following error:

**User [hue] not defined as proxyuser**

I googled it, and found that it has something to do with some proxyuser setting in hue.ini. Even after doing changes suggested, I couldn't get it working.

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Regards,

Comment: Anyone has any idea about this? Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

If the error happens when using search, it is because Hue is not set as a proxy user as detailed in the [documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/Search/latest/Cloudera-Search-User-Guide/csug_sentry.html#concept_jrk_lzc_fm_unique_1).

Comment: I got this resolved as mentioned in answer above. Thanks for your suggestion anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there was some problem with new version of Solr. I reverted back to default version of Solr shipped with CDH standard distribution and it started working.